# Get substring in ms sql

Tags: t-sql

How to get substring form ReportPath column with some IF ELSE cases where i will have only one column(result) like :

Col. Name

- BusinessSummary
- BusinessSummarySub
- Test
- TestSub
  .....

The original values in the column are

- /Subscriptions/BusinessSummarySubs
- /Reports/BusinessSummary
- /Reports/Test
- /Susbstcriptions/TestSubs
  ......

I have more than 20 different Reports and Subreports, not just BusinessSummary and BusinessSummarySubs

Comment: Perhaps taking a few minutes to look at the documentation would help? e.g. yes, this is RTFM: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181984.aspx

Comment: @Marc B: he's on SQL Server, not Mysql, but your point still stands :)

Comment: @davek: yay for fever and up at 5am muscle memory... fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that I understand exactly what you want :) try this:

```
REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(ReportPath), CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(ReportPath)) -1))
```

What this does is it returns the substring after the last `/`. This will **not** work with text data in SQL Server 2000 or earlier versions.

Comment: see me original question, i had change it. Your code doesn't help me so much, because i have more that 20 different reports and subscriptions, and i want to see the second part of that string. For ex. from /Subscriptions/BusinessSummarySubs only BusinessSummarySubs

Comment: @John Ahhh I see. I must have misunderstood you. I'll re-edit my answer when I have something.